# Date Comparison in Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to compare two DateTimes in flutter and execute a particular function using if statements. However, I have been getting NoSuchMethodError.
Here is my code:

```
DateTime _myNowTime; DateTime _myClickTime 

_getClickTime()async{ FirebaseUser currentUser = await 

FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser(); 


Firestore.instance.collection('user').document(currentUser.uid).snapshots().listen((event) {
 if(event.data.isNotEmpty){ setState(() { _now_time = event['now_time']; 

_click_time = event['click_time']; _myNowTime = _now_time.toDate(); _myClickTime = _click_time.toDate(); 

});
 } }); }
```

I want to create a function:

```
 checkTime(){
 if(_myNowTime.compareTo(_myClickTime) >= 30 minutes){

//do something ...}

}
```

Comment: Here is my Code:

Comment: DateTime _now; DateTime _later;  I want a function to execute if _later minus _now >= 30minutes

Comment: if(_later.compareTo(_now >= 30){//do something}

Comment: Please add your code to the question. It's very confusing reading it on the comments

Answer (score 0):

```
void main() {
  var now = DateTime.now();
  var yesterday = now.subtract(const Duration(days: 1));
  
  if(now == yesterday) {
    print("Dates are the same");
  } else print("Dates are not the same");
}
```

Comment: I tried this method but I'm still getting the NoSuchMethodError.

Comment: Then please post your code. Maybe there are other things going on.

Comment: Here is my code:    DateTime _myNowTime; DateTime _myClickTime _getClickTime()async{
   FirebaseUser currentUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
   Firestore.instance.collection('user').document(currentUser.uid).snapshots().listen((event) {
    if(event.data.isNotEmpty){
      setState(() {
      _now_time = event['now_time'];
      
      _click_time = event['click_time'];
      _myNowTime = _now_time.toDate();
      _myClickTime = _click_time.toDate();
     
      });
    }
    
  });

}

Comment: I want to create a function checkTime(){ if(_myNowTime.compareTo(_myClickTime)) >= 30 minutes{//do something ...}}

Comment: @QOU: It’s likely other readers will have the same question. Will you edit your answer to include that code?